# Change GNOME terminal background color on fly

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, terminal

Is it possible to change the background (or window) color of open terminal window on Ubuntu GNOME environment? I would like to do this for tagging purpose when working with multiple terminals.

Comment: see linked dupe question and answer, it has a nice chart of colour codes.  there are also many more similar questions with answer on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do so in GNOME Terminal and a few other (although not all) terminal emulators using the OSC 11 escape sequence with a color name or an #RGB code, e.g.:

```
echo -ne '\e]11;yellow\a'
```

or

```
echo -ne '\e]11;#abcdef\a'
```

Similarly, use number 10 instead of 11 for the default text color.

Comment: can I also change the color of text? Awesome trick anyway